# do multiple $group in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello I have this mongoDB database schema:

```
Module: {
    code_module:String,
    designation_module:String,
    année:Number,
    coéfficient:Number
    listEpreuves: [{
        code_epreuve:String,
        nature_epreuve:String,
        Resultat: [{
            student_lastname:String,
            student_firstname:String,
            note:Number
        }]
    }]
}
```

And i would like to have for each student the marks he had by test and by module
ex :

```
john smith: {[
    biologie:[
        epreuve1:12,
        epreuve2:13,
        epreuve3:7
    ],
    physique: [
        epreuve1:13, 
        epreuve2:18
    ],
    Maths: [
        epreuve1:17,
        epreuve2:10,
        epreuve3:7,5
    ]
}]
```

Aggregation pipeline attempt:

```js
Moddulle.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      "listEpreuves.resultat.nom_etudiant": 1,
      "listEpreuves.resultat.prenom_etudiant": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        nom: "$listEpreuves.resultat.nom_etudiant",
        prenom: "$listEpreuves.resultat.prenom_etudiant"
      },
      modules: {
        $push: {
          code_moddulle: "$code_moddulle",
          designation_moddulle: "$designation_moddulle",
          epreuves: "$listEpreuves"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      nom: "$_id.nom",
      prenom: "$_id.prenom",
      modules: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Which fields in the collection's documents hold the values like `biologie`, `epreuve1`, etc.?

Comment: Seems like that could be done in a single $group with $cond and $push.  Can you give a little more detail about how you have tried to do this?

Comment: @rickhg biologie is in the field "designation_moddulle" in moddulle collection ,and epreuve is in the epreuve collection represented by "code_epreuve" field

Comment: @Joe  I tried several solutions the last one is: `Moddulle.aggregate([
  { $sort: { "listEpreuves.resultat.nom_etudiant": 1, "listEpreuves.resultat.prenom_etudiant": 1 } },
  {    $group: { _id: {    nom: "$listEpreuves.resultat.nom_etudiant",
        prenom: "$listEpreuves.resultat.prenom_etudiant"
      },
      modules: {
        $push: { code_moddulle: "$code_moddulle",
          designation_moddulle: "$designation_moddulle",
          epreuves: "$listEpreuves"
        }} }  },
    { $project: {
      _id: 0, nom: "$_id.nom", prenom: "$_id.prenom",
      modules: 1 }}]);
`